# ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG didn't encode japanese characters properly

Tags: jfreechart

Any one knows the answer?
I create a Jfreechart, and use ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG to save the chart into a png image. But when I open the image file, all japanese characters inside the jfreechart are shown as squares.

Please help!!

Thanks,
APF

Comment: Are the required fonts on your system and accessible to Java?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117271).

Comment: Hi trashgod, do you mean the installed language package on the server or something in JRE?

Comment: Both; the required font must be installed and accessible to the JRE executing the servlet container.